# HTML with CSS isn't working

Tags: html, css, class, web

I am encountering some weird problems. I am trying to create a black box that is going to be the background of a video and some text but after i have entered the CSS the black box doesn't show up. not only that I experimented by making the .videoBlock div as a comment. In that I found out that any code right after the .dwBlock div doesn't seem to work with the CSS. for example the footer disappeared after i marked the .videoBlock div as a comment. Please any help will be appreciated! Thanks a lot!!    Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="wrapOverall">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="navMain">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>            
        </ul>
    </div><!--End of navMain-->
  </div><!--End of header-->
  <div class="wrapBlocks">
    <div class="psBlock"></div><!--End of psBlock-->
    <div class="dwBlock"></div><!--End of dwBlock-->
  </div><!--End of Overall block wrap-->
  <div id="videoblock"></div><!--End of videoBlock-->
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="social"></div><!--End of social-->
  </div><!--End of footer-->
</div><!--End of wrapOverall-->
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.wrapOverall {
background:url(images/bg_main.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
width:1024px;
height:1024px;
}
.header {
height:176px;
background:url(images/bg_header.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.navMain {
}
.wrapBlocks {
margin-top:28px;
}
.psBlock {
height: 235px;
width: 512px;
float:left;
background:url(images/bg_ps.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.dwBlock {
height: 235px;
width: 512px;
float:right;
background:url(images/bg_dw.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.videoblock {
width: 993px;
height: 348px;
background-color:#000;
}
.footer {
width: 1024px;
height:176px;
background:url(images/bg_header.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x; 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code with your .videoBlock div?

Comment: @Mouli The code block was not formatted properly, it was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The float elements are creating problem try giving them base with clear both.

```
  <div class="wrapBlocks">
    <div class="psBlock"></div><!--End of psBlock-->
    <div class="dwBlock"></div><!--End of dwBlock-->
    <div style='clear:both'></div> <!-- above two float element is causing this issue -->  
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes i do... you can count the number of opening div and closing div. The example you shared do not match the opening number of div with the closing number of div...seems you have edited it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your CSS not in your html code, you are using an id="videoblock" but in your CSS you are referenced as a class .videoblock, change . by # in your CSS like #videoblock and work fine.

```
#videoblock {
width: 993px;
height: 348px;
background-color:#000;
}
```

Can you view demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcqjb/):